# How to add up scraped strings representing integers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

How would I add up all the floats that I scraped?

```
for post in posts:
    numberOfItems = numberOfItems + 1
    print(numberOfItems)
    value = float(re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", post.text))
    print("Chaos orbs: %s" % value)
    print(value)
```

Like this, print(value1 + value2 + value3) but, it will be a random amount that I will not know, so I can't make variables

Comment: Can you give an example of `post.text`? Or at least confirm that the `value` you calculate is returning the correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sum()`:

```
for post in posts:
    ... # rest of code snippet you posted

print(sum(float(re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", post.text)) for post in posts))
```

outside of your for loop will add up all the values and print out the sum.

---

Alternatively, if you want to use your existing for loop somehow to avoid iterating twice, how about:

```
summed_values = 0
for post in post:
    ... # rest of code snippet you posted
    summed_values += value
```

Comment: Thanks, Any idea how I would divide that?

Comment: @Nevermind123 Divide what? The summed value? Just divide the summed value like you normally would any number: `summed_value/some_divisor`. If using the first method, just divide the `sum` call instead: `sum(...)/some_divisor`. If you plan on asking followups that don't relate to the character of the question you asked, please ask them as a separate question - that way, more people can help you rather than just I. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve this:

```
post="1.0  2.0  3.0\n 1.5 2.3"
print sum(map(float,post.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are scraping, but this should extract the numeric values:

```
import re

s = "abc 12.25 def 20 df20.5 $10,000.50"

>>> re.findall(r"([\d.?]+)", re.sub(",", "", s))
['12.25', '20', '20.5', '10000.50']
```

This regex removes the commas from the strings, and passes the result to another regex that finds all digits (`\d`) which may or may not have a decimal (`.?`).

The list of integer strings can easily be summed:

```
>>> sum(float(n) for n in re.findall(r"([\d.?]+)", re.sub(",", "", s)))
10053.25
```

Which you then total in the outer loop:

```
total_sum = 0
for post in posts:
    ...
    total_sum += sum(float(n) for n in re.findall(r"([\d.?]+)", re.sub(",", "", s)))
    ...
```